# How to keep a clean (rebased) history with 'git-flow'?

Tags: git, git-merge, redmine, rebase, git-flow

I usually prefer rebase for having a clear history (at least on the `master` branch).

Taking a look at [`git-flow`](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) looks like it **needs** to work with merge commits. This feels ugly/untidy because of all the merge commits (I usually rebase), but also because of multiple merge commits related to the same code (`ui-feature1` merged to `ui-development`, then merged to `development`, then merged to `master`; the same even without at `ui-development` branch).

Rebase instead would be cleaner/prettier, but it creates replayed-duplicated commits, so:

- it is more complicated to understand where to branch from (cause of the risk of diverged branches)
- requires to do additional maintenance (some branches will be always rebased in, while others will need to be deleted and recreated)
- systems like Redmine (whose Issues/Tickets can list all the corresponding repository commits that refer them via `refs #redmine-issue` in the commit message) would show the *source* **and** the *rebased* commit, when `ref`erring the issue in the first source commit.

Is there any middle way?
Any way to have a nice integration of *git-flow* but still having Redmine-issues referenced in commits' message?

How does `git rebase` play with *git-flow*? Are there other valid git workflows that favour *rebase* rather than *merge*? Is it possible to follow *git-flow* without having merge commits?

Comment: Rebase is a very common and valid Git workflow pattern.  Since I don't know anything about `git-flow`, I can't comment further.

Answer (score 2):

You can `rebase` feature branch before merging it to `develop` or `master`  onto corresponding branch like this:

```
git checkout feature/my-super-feature
git rebase develop
git checkout develop
git merge feature/my-super-feature
```

So you will have cleaner history in your `git-flow` But still there is cost for it, as any `rebase` it is rewriting history, in this case only for last commits. So it is for you to find ballance between history being clean and being informative. I am myself only use `rebase` on feature branches last commits to squash fixups in one commit like this:

```
git rebase -i --autosquash HEAD~2
```

One more option to use `merge --squash` to merge feature branch. It is most "clean" but you loose all you commits. Sometimes it is useful.